# Header content not displaying in IE6

Tags: html, header, z-index, joomla3.0

I have used Joomla 3.3 ("tk_responsi_free" template) to build my website. But when I am trying to view it in IE7 the sub menu section getting suppressed by other modules. So I have added little bit of CSS code in "custom.css":

```
#header {
    z-index: 999;
}
```

This solved my problem in IE7. But now I am not able to view the contents which were written under Header tag in IE6. I have removed the above CSS code and also used conditional statement. But the problem remains.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without a code snippet of your code that would be hard to find what is wrong. I would suggest you to avoid IE6 support and add a browser update waring plugin from: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/browsers-a-web-standards

Comment: @emmanuel I just need the basic display in IE6. Only menu headers image that will serve my purpose. Code snippet added.

Comment: Do you check ie6 supports html5??

Answer (score 0):

IE6, a browser from pre-history, can't parse html5 tags. Are you even loading an html5shiv? Without it IE6 doesn't even know the header tag is there. Pretty sure your template will not support IE6, so if you want IE6 support a free responsive template is not the best choice.

Expecting that is like expecting a transistor radio to play a Blu-ray disc. As far as IE6 is concerned html5 doesn't exist, neither does css3.

Comment: Yes i am loading html5shiv for the browsers less than IE8. I just require the basic view of my menus not the actual one. And at first i am getting the views but after changing z-index the menu display stopped. And @Seth Warburton I am not trying to play a Blu-ray disc with transistor radio, i am just trying to test that the transistor radio is still alive or not providing the power supply.